# Hierarchical Comments Retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to help retrieving hierarchial comments. I'm finding hard time doing so. I could retrieve one level of comments that is

```
-Main Comment
--Reply1
--Reply2
--Reply3
```

Replies that are under Reply1, Reply2, etc are not retrieved. The actual replies in database look like this:

```
-Main Comment
--Reply1
---ReplyA
----ReplyA1
---ReplyB
----ReplyB1
--Reply2
---ReplyA
--Reply3
```

As you see main comment can have multiple replies and a reply also can have descending replies and the list goes on.

I need to build a commenting system that is similar to vbulletin forum commenting system. I think vbulletin uses a hierarchical commenting system.

Feel free to provide supporting resources.

Comment: you should include some more technical info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursion for iterating throught this kind of hierarchical data.
http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Recursion-in-PHP/

http://devzone.zend.com/article/1235

Iterate through tree and on each node call childrens

```
function rIterate($data, $sep = '-') {

 foreach($data as $key => $replyChild) {
     echo $sep . $replyChild['item'];
     rItearate($replyChild, $sep . '-');
 }
```

}

I havent tested but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

If you partition your tables into something like this, it will be helpful.
The key here is to store the ancestor and descendant for every comment, no matter where it appears in the hierarchy. (Not just the immediate parent).

(Notice that comments 4 and 5 below are actually replying to comment 3.)

Comment: Seems interesting not complicated at all. I'll give it a shot and respond back...

Comment: Didn't solve it yet. Recursion is the only solution for now...Thanks for the try.